# print one letter after the other with useEffect and setInterval

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, setinterval, use-effect

I'm trying to understand what is the best way to create a component that prints one letter after the other every some period of time (like a type-writer) using `useEffect` and `setInterval`

- this way will cause the interval to run forever:

```js
function Printer({ str }) {
  const [val, setVal] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setVal((preVal) => preVal + 1);
    }, 200);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, [str]);

  return <div>{str.slice(0, val)}</div>;
}
```

- while this one will complain that `val` is a missing dependency to the useEffect dependency array:

```js
function Printer({ str }) {
  const [val, setVal] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (val < str.length) {
        setVal((preVal) => preVal + 1);
      } else {
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
    }, 200);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, [str]);

  return <div>{str.slice(0, val)}</div>;
}
```

- and if adding `val` into the dependency array - we are setting multiple redundant intervals (and removing them so this just feels somehow bad):

```js
function Printer({ str }) {
  const [val, setVal] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (val < str.length) {
        setVal((preVal) => preVal + 1);
      } else {
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
    }, 200);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, [str, val]);

  return <div>{str.slice(0, val)}</div>;
}
```

not sure if I'm missing something regarding useEffect, the dependency array or this is it just the linter trolling me.

Comment: Your last approach looks good, just try with no dependencies on your useEffect, so it gets called only once.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `useRef()` to store the end condition (`stop`):

```js
const { useState, useRef, useEffect } = React;

function Printer({ str }) {
  const [val, setVal] = useState(0);
  const stop = useRef();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    stop.current = val === str.length;
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      if(stop.current) clearInterval(interval);
      else setVal((preVal) => preVal + 1);
    }, 200);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, []);

  return <div>{str.slice(0, val)}</div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Printer str="cats" />,
  root
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Put both the string prop and the state index into the dependency array, and to make things easier, use a timeout instead of an interval. Also add a callback that runs when the string prop changes so you can reset the state index to 0.

```js
const Printer = ({ str }) => {
  const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (index < str.length) {
      const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
        setIndex(index + 1);
        return () => clearTimeout(timeoutId);
      }, 200);
      return () => clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    }
  }, [index, str]);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setIndex(0);
  }, [str]);
  return <div>{str.slice(0, index)}</div>;
}
const App = () => {
  const [str, setStr] = React.useState('');
  return (
    <div>
      <input value={str} onChange={(e) => setStr(e.currentTarget.value)} />
      <Printer str={str} />
    </div>
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Comment: Yeah, I guess it's not needed. I was thinking to reset the index *immediately* when the prop changes, instead of after a very short delay.

Comment: I can see the reason behind using `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval` but isn't using a `setState` (in our case `setIndex`) and including the state (in our case `index`) within the dependency array a bad practice (in general)?

Comment: @mikey.nagler There's absolutely nothing wrong with it in general. Since you want a subsequent state change to occur after a prior state change, putting the setter inside makes perfect sense - it's the logic you're looking for, and there's no code smell about it. Of course, if you didn't have the `if (index < str.length) {`, it'd go on forever - which one might want, or one might not want.

Comment: @ CertainPerformance so this is ok as long as we are protected by the code itself (or the logic behind it) ?

Comment: Yep - as long as you're not setting the state for the same variable being observed *immediately, synchronously* inside the hook (which would be pretty weird), there's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: also, does it have any effect to actually clear a timeout that is currently running?
I don't think this function for cleaning is being called anywhere.

Comment: Yes, clearing a timeout that is running will result in the timeout callback not being called when the time is up

Comment: The cleanup function isn't being called (usefully) in this small snippet here, but in a larger application, if the `Printer` component might get dismounted, putting in a cleanup function is good to avoid React's no-op warnings (and is good practice anyway - with asynchronous tasks, make sure to always clean them up for however the component may get used in the future).

Comment: I understand the cleanup function being returned from the `useEffect` callback.
but I don't think the function being returned from the `setTimeout` callback is actually being called anywhere

Comment: It will be called (1) when the effect is going to run again (not important here), and (2) when the component gets dismounted (this *is* important, to avoid no-ops, React warnings, and potential memory leaks)